# Can I link folders from an external drive to show up on my c drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, symbolic-link

I am running Windows 10 and my c: drive is almost full.  I have a d: drive but the partitions are not adjacent, so apparently I cannot reallocate that drive to my c: drive.  I have managed to link folders from my d: drive to my c: drive so that I can access them on my c: drive and they get backed up by OneDrive as part of my c: drive. (although I can't remember now how I did that, and can't find where I found the instructions to set it up)
My question is, can I set up the same arrangement of linking a folder to my c: drive from an external drive, so that that data will also be backed up to OneDrive? And if so, how can I do that?

Comment: run `mklink /d d:\path\to\target\folder linkname` in a command prompt that was run as administrator to create the link. /d can also be /j, but I usually use /d to create a soft directory junction. Once the link is made, you can move your data over to that folder. You can also rename a folder, then create a link in its place and move the data over.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a ***hard link*** or a ***junction*** from the one drive to the other.

You *can* do it from the command line but I myself find  [this tool](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html)  makes it very easy to do.  Once installed, simply RIGHT DRAG your folder like you are trying to create a shortcut and you will see the menu from the shell extension as an option.

If you want to do it from the command line, use the `mklink` utility built into windows.  You can find a command line reference for this tool  [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)  but here is the simple way to use it.

`mklink /j <link path> <target path>` would create a "link path" *junction* in the target path location.  To be honest.. look at their help.. not mine. ;)

*ALMOST* no programs are aware that you have linked a folder (rather than being on the original partition) so you should be good to go. :)

I myself use it for similar reasons.. I have a small C SSD drive and a GIGANTIC D HDD drive.  If a program isn't running, you can MOVE all of the big data to the other drive and link it back without anything becoming the wiser.

Good Luck. :)

Comment: +1 although I would have liked it a lot if you would also include the mklink steps. Its always good to be able to do something without requiring external tools because the link can become invalid, but the instruction never does. Also, I really had to look hard to find the option. Its not labelled logically.

Comment: Added @LPChip.  You are right (as usual).. feel free to edit the text to make it more usable.